# Rscript cant find file using cygwin path

Tags: r, cygwin, rscript

I'm running cygwin on Windows 7 and am having problems with Rscript.
I'd like to run an R file as R script in a bin directory, but Rscript seems to be have problems with cygwin path names.  Here an example Rscript file.

```
$ which test.R
/cygdrive/e/Glenn/bin/test.R
$ ls -l /cygdrive/e/Glenn/bin/test.R
-rwxr-xr-x+ 1 Glenn None 36 Jan  6 08:06 /cygdrive/e/Glenn/bin/test.R
$ cat /cygdrive/e/Glenn/bin/test.R
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
print("hi")
```

The basic problem is an error when I try to run test.R

```
$ test.R
Fatal error: cannot open file '/cygdrive/e/Glenn/bin/test.R': No such file or directory
```

In diagnosing the problem, I found I can execute the code using Rscript explicitly, but not if a cygwin-style path is used.

```
$ Rscript /cygdrive/e/Glenn/bin/test.R
Fatal error: cannot open file '/cygdrive/e/Glenn/bin/test.R': No such file or directory

$ Rscript E:/Glenn/bin/test.R
[1] "hi"
$ which Rscript
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/R/R-3.1.2/bin/Rscript
```

I'd like to fix the problem or find a good workaround.

After understanding the problem better thanks to the answer by @varro, I wrote this hack:

```
$ cat ~/bin/myRscript
#!/bin/bash
winpath=$(cygpath -d "$1")
shift
Rscript $winpath "$@"
```

Then I rewrote test.sh:

```
$ cat ~/bin/test.R
#!/usr/bin/env myRscript
print("hi")
```

It works, but I don't like the hack and I'd like a more portable solution.

```
$ which test.R
/cygdrive/e/Glenn/bin/test.R
$ test.R
[1] "hi"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the location of Rscript under "Program Files", it doesn't look like it's a Cygwin program, so of course it will not understand Cygwin paths.  It you want to run it in a Cygwin environment, you have to install the Cygwin version of R, which I believe is available under Cygwin Ports.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense!  However, I'm concerned about installing the Cygwin version of R since I'm a heavy R user and use RStudio, etc., especially if R is not supported in Cygwin proper.

Comment: I can understand that, but you'll have to balance the advantages and disadvantages of using a Cygwin version of R here.  What I *can* tell you is that a non-Cygwin R is not going to be able to understand Cygwin paths.  I personally have never used R, so I cannot give you any advice beyond this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good advice.  You'll see I edited the post to show an ugly hack that seems to work -- at least for my current problem.

Comment: Congratulations on coming up with a work-around, even though it isn't the  most elegant of solutions.